# Chemical Engineering subject classification

Tags: tools, curriculum

Our department is working on revamping our curriculum and I thought it would be a good time to align ourselves with any internationally available subject classification schemes for Chemical Engineering. My goal is to automate the process of checking coverage of topics in the new curriculum to avoid important topics falling through the cracks.

I have found the [AIChE Body of Knowledge](http://www.aiche.org/about/press/releases/07-16-2015/new-body-knowledge-chemical-engineers-will-guide-chemical-engineering-training-career-skills), but this appears not to allow for coding of topics. I'm looking for something similar to the [AMS Mathematics Subject Classification](http://www.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html), which allows for a relatively exhaustive list of topics as well as providing short codes which can be used to count automatically which modules provide which topics.

Does anybody know of a systematic coding scheme for Chemical Engineering topics? Failing that, what strategies or tools have you used during curriculation to code the topics and check for coverage?

Comment: Are you sure that you want such a scheme?  They are typically very slowly updated and out of date.

Comment: @jakebeal I would be developing a scheme like it to describe our curriculum anyway, but then it would be unique to our institution and not allow for easy sharing across institutions. Whenever possible I prefer to use an existing coding scheme instead of creating my own to avoid proliferation of schemes. I don't really see the down side. If some items aren't included in the scheme at least I match those that are.

Comment: Fair enough --- I just wanted to raise the concern, since I have found that the [ACM classification for computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACM_Computing_Classification_System) often makes cuts across subject matter that seem to do more harm than good, separating elements that should be combined to give a more unified and modern picture of the field.

Comment: Do you think that classification is a futile activity then? How does one go about harmonising the descriptions that different people have for what they do?

Comment: I think classification is useful for some things, but that there are often multiple different types of concerns in play (i.e., [heterarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterarchy) rather than hierarchy), and most classification systems that I have encountered do not support this fact well.  For example, your curriculum probably deals with core information and also forms of practical experience (e.g. labs) and exposure to current topics and possible other things as well, and some of are likely served better than others by any given system.  In short: classification is a tool, not a goal.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep in that in mind. I still feel like it is a useful component of the activity, though.